# Umgekehrte Wortstellung und der Genitiv, z. B: »des Wanderers Schritte« statt »die Schritte des Wanderers«

Tags: genitive

In Bücher habe ich ab und zu die im Titel erwähnte Genitivform gelesen und ich habe den Eindruck, dass sie entweder veraltet ist oder nur in poetischer Sprache oder festen Ausdrücken benutzt wird.

Ist meine Vermutung korrekt? Wenn ja, wann wurde dieser Genitiv benutzt? Gibt es auch heutzutage Situationen, in denen es natürlich ist, diese Genitivform zu benutzen?

Comment: Ich bin auf des Rätsels Lösung gespannt. Dann werden wir wissen, was des Pudels Kern ist.

Comment: Ich würde sagen dass es eine aktuelle Form ist, die normal sein sollte, aber unter der allgemeinen Genetivphobie leidet - "dem Wanderer seine Schritte" und "die Schritte von dem Wanderer" hört man wahrlich häufig, obwohl sie falsch sind. Da Poeten und Literaten die Sprache besser kennen und stärker achten verwenden diese eher deren richtige Form, so auch den geschmähten Genitiv. Veraltet ist es aber noch nicht.

Comment: @user unknown: Ich finde schon, dass es veraltet ist. Würde jemand zum Beispiel in einen Polizeibericht schreiben: *"Des Mörders Tatwaffe wurde im Wagen gefunden."*?

Comment: Wenn ich Polizist wäre - ich würde es schreiben. Wieso denn nicht? Weil es eine Tautologie ist - entweder es ist die Tatwaffe, dann - sofern es Mord ist - ... - er hat sie blos ausgeliehen? Er ist Mörder in einem anderen Fall? Also im Normalfall würde ich `Die Tatwaffe wurde im Wagen gefunden` oder `Im Wagen fand sich die Tatwaffe` verwenden. Aus lokal üblichen Diktionen, wie einem Polizeibericht, kann ich jedenfalls nicht auf die Allgemeinheit schließen. Ich bastle noch an der Katzen Schlafplatz. Der Worte sind genug gewechselt! Ach Mist - was immer man sagt, Göthe war schneller.

Comment: Mir fällt da noch eine Benutzung dieser Wortstellung im Dialekt ein, ich hörte schon so Sachen wie `der Mutter ihr Auto steht in der Einfahrt`. Wobei das dann langer nicht mehr so poetisch klingt, zumindest in meinen Ohren.

Comment: @0x6d64: Das sollte aber entweder `Mutters Auto steht in der Einfahrt` (meiner, unserer Mutter) oder `das Auto der Mutter` (eine Mutter) heißen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Die Schritte des Wanderers" ist heutzutage schriftsprachlicher Standard. Mündlich und beim informellen Schreiben wird der Genitiv aber inzwischen oft vermieden, entweder durch "falsche" Dative (die oft aus den Dialekten stammen) oder durch Umformulierung. 
Dabei sind possessive Genitive bei Personen ("Papas Auto", "Maries Freund") eher gebräuchlich als bei Dingen, wohl weil der dabei meist nötige Artikel als gestelzt empfunden wird ("die Türen des Hauses"). Der Genitiv als Objektkasus ist mündlich fast gänzlich verschwunden.

"Des Wanderers Schritte" ist heute auch schriftlich nur noch in poetischer Sprache oder als stilistisches Zitat möglich. Ausnahmen sind feste Verbindungen, also vor allem Sprichwörter und Redensarten, z. B. "des Pudels Kern", die man durchaus auch noch mündlich hört.